# Sitecore 'Item could not be found from query string. '

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore-dms, sitecore-ecm

I am facing an intermittent issue with Sitecore CMS 6.5 and ECM 1.3.1 rev 111202. When a user opens an email from ecm - it isn't being reflected in the engagement plan and it happens for emails sent via ECM, in the logs the error message 'Item could not be found from query string. [ID is "{840DACC9-60C1-4705-BCAC-D188BD7D2AD8}"' is displayed. The item exists in the backend (can find it via the GUID above) and also in the Sitecore master database. Inspection of the request to the server via fiddler reveals that the url is structured correctly:

myurl/sitecore/RegisterEmailOpened.aspx?sc_itemid=%7b840DACC9-60C1-4705-BCAC-D188BD7D2AD8%7d&sc_camp=FBCF7F99F5C74F67BD8D976A7C16B7A1&ec_as=FA987FCE345347D4BA1C5584455A3AB5

I have checked and rechecked the database connection strings but everything seems to be correct. This has had me stuck for a while, so any help appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is shown because the item is not published to the Web database. You can consider it as an ECM bug.
But it seems that it does not influence the process of moving a recipient in the engagement plan. Try to publish a certain message and check it again.